# Benefits of inline caching

Tags: javascript, v8

Is there any way to figure out how many and what accesses in JavaScript program are actually utilizing inline caching technique? or are majorly contributing to improve overall performance using inline caching?

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to [V8 Chrome page](https://developers.google.com/v8/design) then you will find it there:

> V8 compiles JavaScript source code directly into machine code when it is first executed. There are no intermediate byte codes, no interpreter. Property access is handled by inline cache code that may be patched with other machine instructions as V8 executes.
>
> During initial execution of the code for accessing a property of a given object, V8 determines the object's current hidden class. V8 optimizes property access by predicting that this class will also be used for all future objects accessed in the same section of code and uses the information in the class to patch the inline cache code to use the hidden class. If V8 has predicted correctly the property's value is assigned (or fetched) in a single operation. If the prediction is incorrect, V8 patches the code to remove the optimisation.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. I think some accesses will benefit more in terms of performance due to inline caching as compared to some other accesses.  For ex., Obj.x being executed 10000 times when Obj always points to same hidden class. 
I want to distinguish such accesses.

Also, can you help me in understanding the patches introduced due to change in the state of inline caching? For example, uninitialized -> premonomorphic -> monomorphic->polymorphic->megamorphic etc..

Comment: @Monika:- Yes all the access will be benefited. As far as the drawback is concerned then it is hard to say that there are any drawbacks until you are not using it wisely. You can also read this [good reference](https://github.com/sq/JSIL/wiki/Optimizing-dynamic-JavaScript-with-inline-caches#why-are-you-using-an-inline-cache-in-javascript)

Comment: I will certainly go through it. Also, I understand that for every access, 3-4 additional instructions will be added to take in to consideration inline caching at runtime. Is that true? Won't it add lot of overhead to the program under execution since total number of accesses in the program will be generally large?